# How to get a text from .kv textbox in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm Trying to get a text from textfield in .kv file to my .py file and I am having problem using ids and by changing and trying everything i get diffrent errors and sometimes no errors but no result.
I really need help with this.
.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = 360,640

class MyGrid(ScreenManager):

    def Generate(self, root):
        self.get_screen("Grid").ids.filename.text = ""
        self.get_screen("Grid").ids.content.text = ""

class mainApp(MDApp):
    Builder.load_file("main.kv")
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
<MyGrid>:
    Screen:
        name: "Grid"
        MDLabel:
            text: "QR Code Generator"
            font_size: 36
            pos_hint: {"center_y": .93}
            halign: "center"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .1
            padding: "10dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_y": .75}
            MDTextField:
                id: filename
                hint_text: "Enter File Name..."
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .1
            padding: "10dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_y": .6}
            MDTextField:
                id: content
                hint_text: "Enter Url To Generate QR Code..."
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Generate"
            text_color: "white"
            line_color: "blue"
            md_bg_color: "blue"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "center_y": .48}
            on_press: root.Generate(root)
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Clear"
            text_color: "white"
            line_color: "#FA8072"
            md_bg_color: "#FA8072"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .7, "center_y": .48}
```

I'm a begginer using kivy so I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Generate(self, root):
    filename = self.ids.filename.text 
    content =  self.ids.content.text 
    print(f"file name = {filename}")
    print(f"content = {content}")
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm not getting any error hopefully but the is no result.
I mean its not getting the text I enter, I just get this as a result :
file name = 
content =

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?